# How to open a smalltalk image in squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Super noob question here. Seems basic but I'm not understanding how to do this.

Someone sent me a smalltalk program "program.app" and now I want to open it and run it in squeak.

How do I do this? I have squeak open on my ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Since you only wrote "Smalltalk program", are you certain that this is meant to be run with Squeak? Because in general you cannot run products of one Smalltalk implementation with another implementation. Also, if program.app is a collection of Smalltalk source code, the steps would be different than if it were or had an image file of some sort. My current answer assumes the latter. Please add more details about program.app to the question should it not help.

Comment: @JayK yes, the readme in the program folder just says run with squeak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what exactly your "program.app" is. In general you need a virtual machine (the squeak executable suitable to your operating system) and an image file (the memory snapshot including the Smalltalk bytecode of all the methods) to run. You would then run the VM with the image as a command line argument from the shell, not from within a running Squeak process.

Note: if you do not trust the source of this "program.app", consider the risk of running an unknown program. A Smalltalk image will execute code without any input from your side once started.

If program.app is a directory, search for an .image file in there. Once you have located the image file and your Squeak VM executable, run the VM with the image as a command line argument:

```
squeak program.image
```

If program.app is a directory it could also be a "bundle". That is, it could bring both an image and a VM to run it. For example, the Squeak All-in-One bundle downloadable from squeak.org includes one image file and three VMs: one VM for each major platform, plus start scripts in the top-level directory. If program.app includes a VM, it may work best to run the image with that VM:

```
program.app/path/to/squeak program.app/path/to/program.image
```

Maybe it even has a `squeak.sh` start script, like the All-in-One bundle.

If your "program.app" is not a directory, please ask the person from whom you have obtained program.app what that is and how to run it. If it is the renamed image file already, run the VM with it: `squeak program.app`.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the detailed response. I've found that it is the all-in-one bundle with the squeak.sh. I can run it but squeak does not have permission to run it. So thanks for getting me to the next challenge!